# Keeping aspect ratio of divs with a background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a background image that has a large blue diagonal across the back where we want some of our content to line up with.

I am having issues keeping the content inline as it resizes, though (the background diagonal gets bigger or smaller, making the alignment off).

Current css:

```
  background: url('../../../img/bg.png') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
```

What might I need to keep the aspect ratio the same regardless of resize?

https://jsfiddle.net/wb166bdo/11/

Comment: This seems confusing - you mention that the background diagonal changes size which is undesirable, but then after you say that you want to keep the aspect ratio the same. Can you clear this up?

Comment: Okay, so, say I want the text to stay aligned along the blue diagonal.

Right now, if I resize the window, the blue diagonal will increase or decrease in size due to the background resizing (and thus moving it up or down). The text will not stay aligned to the diagonal element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maintain the ratio you could give a top or bottom padding in percentages that equals the ratio wanted. If the image is 200px x 100 px the padding will be 50%. The top and bottom padding in % refers to the width of the parent [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top).

Comment: This actually works reasonably well (padding-top/bottom: 50% seems to lock the background mostly in place).

It's in a section tag, though; So there is a huge gap between bits of content at the top and bottom (IE, I have stuff placed at the top of the section tag, that is now moved down a lot, and there's a huge gap at the bottom).

Comment: Actually, with just incredibly massive negative margins, I can make it work.

Ugly but it's a fix for now.